# How to check UseMsal for when to render component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, azure-ad-msal

I'm looking at the sample code for UseMsal [found here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-react/docs/hooks.md#usemsal-hook) and I'm confused by the fact it seems to think it is returning a value from the hook. Either I'm not testing this code sample correct or it's wrong. I don't see how the token value is returned and then part of the if/then logic later. Here's the sample they provided:

```
const { instance, accounts, inProgress } = useMsal();
let accessToken = null;
useEffect(() => {
    if (inProgress === "none" && accounts.length > 0) {
        // Retrieve an access token
        accessToken = instance.acquireTokenSilent({
            account: accounts[0],
            scopes: ["User.Read"]
        }).then(response => {
            if (response.accessToken) {
                return response.accessToken;
            }
            return null;
        });
    }
}, [inProgress, accounts, instance]);

if (inProgress === "login") {
    // Render loading component
} else if (accessToken) {
    // Call your api and render component
}
```

When I see this code my assumption is they think that `accessToken` is set to NULL before the `useEffect` and then updated so that outside it can then be referenced. In my sample, `accessToken` is updated in the hook but not updated outside of the hook.

I thought I read a similar question on hooks and returning values which said the correct approach was to have the hook update state variables. Does this example make sense? Should that return be updating the token variable? Maybe this is just a tiny piece of a larger code base? Or should this example be rewritten to make that variable set in state?

Answer (score 1):

See It seems that instance.acquireTokenSilent is **asynchronous** call hence your .then block is executed only after response is received and you don’t know when is that going to happen, hence use state variables ( either using **useState** or **useReducer** as this is simple state update I would recommend going for useState) then whenever your state will get updated component will re-render. I hope this solves your issue. Let me know if you need anything more.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was debating making a note in the documentation about this but since I was just trying to learn the code I didn't want to rule out the possibility that it was something I didn't understand.

Comment: Your welcome, you can even write your own custom hook for this. It will be better for reusability